# How would you iterate a vector?

Tags: c++, for-loop, foreach, iteration, cycle

This is [my code](http://cpp.sh/9uub):

```
std::vector<int> array;
array.push_back(1);
array.push_back(2);
array.push_back(3);
array.push_back(4);
array.push_back(5);

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if(array[i]==2 || array[i]==5) {
        array.erase(array.begin() + i);
        printf("### REMOVED ###\n", array[i], i);
    } 

    printf("inside val: %d | index: %d\n", array[i], i);
}
```

but as you can see, it outputs:

```
inside val: 1 | index: 0
### REMOVED ###
inside val: 3 | index: 1
inside val: 4 | index: 2
### REMOVED ###
inside val: 5 | index: 3
```

when my "expectation" is:

```
inside val: 1 | index: 0
### REMOVED ###
inside val: 2 | index: 1
inside val: 3 | index: 2
inside val: 4 | index: 3
### REMOVED ### 
inside val: 5 | index: 4
```

it "messes" with index/array's size during manipulation of itself, because will change memory pointer and size of the target.

My habit is to use a `foreach statement` and [iterate a collection (`C#/.Net`)](http://rextester.com/EZMYM12731), where even if I remove/add elements during the iteration, the next one is always the next from the beginning list.

How would you do it with `C++`?

Comment: Do you have an example in C#?

Comment: @TAS: sure: http://rextester.com/EZMYM12731

Comment: Albeit your question is sufficiently clear to be answerable, you do not perform any deletion in your C# snippet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical form of a `for` loop that may remove elements is the following :

```
for(auto i = begin(coll); i != end(coll);) {

    // ...

    if(hasToRemove)
        i = coll.erase(i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to run it: http://cpp.sh/273mz

Comment: @markzzz that's because `i` is now an iterator. You must dereference it (`*i`) to access the value it refers to, and you can use `i - begin(coll)` to retrieve the index into the vector.

Comment: Can you post a plain example? I'm not able to figure out the results I'd like.

Comment: Here what I've done: http://cpp.sh/5no5

Comment: The results are different ### REMOVED ###
inside val: 4 | index: 2
inside val: 5 | index: 3
### REMOVED ###
inside val: 5 | index: 4
### REMOVED ###
inside val: 0 | index: 5
inside val: 0 | index: 5

Comment: @markzzz [There you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4483295800d2ebca).

Comment: no its different. `printf` is at the end. Thus, `Erasing element` string must be written before printf (or cout)...

Comment: @markzzz If you want to use the value you're iterating over, you need to do so before you erase it.

Comment: Who say this? :) No, for some reasons I need to do it after removing the elements.

Comment: @markzzz The fact that an erased object is dead, and its storage gets trampled by its neighbour in the case of a vector ;) -- If your real code needs to erase first at all cost, you have to move the object to a local variable beforehand, and use that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108288/discussion-between-markzzz-and-quentin).

Comment: That's the final working solution: http://cpp.sh/92cat

Answer (score 2):

Use iterators:

```
int ind = 0;
for (auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ) {
    if(*i==2 || *i==5) {
        i = array.erase(i);
        printf("### REMOVED ###\n");
    } 
    else {
    ++i;
    ++ind;
    }

    printf("inside val: %d | index: %d\n", *i, ind);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your code like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    int temp=i;
    if(array[temp]==2 || array[temp]==5) {
        array.erase(array.begin() + temp);
        printf("### REMOVED ###\n", array[temp], temp);
        i--;
    } 

    printf("inside val: %d | index: %d\n", array[temp], temp);
}
```